# If $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_a^x f(t)dt=\infty$, then for any $c \gt a: \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_c^xf(t)dt=\infty$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

This is a straightforward proof (I think), but there was one part of the argument that I was not completely sure of. I have labeled it with a $\color{red}\dagger$.

Claim to prove:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_a^x f(t)dt=\infty$, then for any $c \gt a: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_c^xf(t)dt=\infty$

---

$\color{red}{(\dagger)}$: First, note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_a^x f(t)dt=\infty$ implicitly establishes that $f$ is integrable on $[a,N]$ for any $N \geq a$. Therefore, by definition of integrable, $f$ must be bounded on $[a,N]$. This means that $\displaystyle \int_a^c f(t)dt$ is a finite quantity. Let $\lambda = \displaystyle \int_a^c f(t)dt$.

By assumption, we know that: $\forall M \in \mathbb R: \exists N_M \in \mathbb R: \forall x \gt N_M: \displaystyle \int_a^x f(t)dt \gt M$. Consider the $N$ that corresponds to $M+\lambda$.

Then we have that $\forall x \gt N: \displaystyle \int_a^xf(t)dt \gt M+\lambda$. Next, note that $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t)dt= \int_a^c f(t)dt + \int_c^x f(t)dt$. This means that:$$\int_c^xf(t)dt \gt M+\lambda-\int_a^c f(t)dt=M \implies \int_c^xf(t)dt \gt M$$

---

**Edit**: the converse of this statement should be true, too, assuming the rationale behind $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$ is correct.

Therefore, we can make the following statement, as well:

> Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,\infty)$. If $\exists c \in [a,\infty): \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_c^xf(t)dt=\infty$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_a^xf(t)dt = \infty$

Comment: Boundedness of $f$ is unnecessary (and might be false, depending on which theory of integration you consider). Integrability on any $[a,N]$ is sufficient to define $\lambda$ and claim it is finite.

Comment: @AnneBauval the definition I have been taught is the Darboux definition (equivalent to Riemann), which requires boundedness of $f$ on $[a,b]$ to be known before I can even assert that $\int_a^b f$ exists. With this requirement, I then know that $\alpha=\sup\{f(x): x \in [a,b]\}$ and $\beta=\inf\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$ both exist, which means that $\beta\cdot(b-a) \leq \int_a^b f \leq \alpha \cdot (b-a)$...i.e. $\int_a^b f$ is finite. How do I ensure that $\int_a^b f$ is finite if I do not stipulate that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: In the definition you have been taught, since we assume that $f$ is integrable on $[a,N]$, we know that $\int_a^Nf$ is finite (no need to recall the hypothesis of the definition).

Comment: @AnneBauval so across all variant definitions of 'integral', when we say that $f$ is *integrable* (through whatever definition) on $[a,b]$, we **always** interpret this as $\int_a^b f$ is **finite**?

Comment: I think so (except when $f$ is supposed to be $\ge0$: in Lebesgue's theory, for any positive measurable function $f$ and positive measure $\mu$, $\int f\,\mathrm d\mu\in[0,+\infty]$, but your $f$ is not supposed $\ge0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for the feedback. Cheers~